# Sphere not following Path

Tags: modeling, animation, objects

I want to make a ball go around in a spiraled circle

[image]

I've created the lines around the figure using the *SimpleDeform* modifier for both twist and bend. However, when I use the Follow Path object constraint, the sphere just travels straight down in the direction of the blue line in the screenshot, disregarding the bent / twisted path.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the Sphere or object that you would like to follow path.
2. Click <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to clear location (If that doesn't work, you can hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and search *Clear Location*. If that doesn't work too, go to *Object -> Clear -> Location*).

A quick suggestion for the *Follow Path Constraint* that helped me is:

1. Select the curve.
2. Go to *Object Settings -> Path Animation -> Frames* and when you change the *Frames* value, it will change the length of the *Follow Path Constraint*.

Comment: hmm. not sure what you mean

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I just updated it. I'm not sure if you downvoted it, but if you did, please un-downvote it :)